# css image jumping to another element on browser scale

Tags: css, browser, overflow, positioning, scaling

Hello I do some css positioning to magento eshop. I am using image for add-to-cart button and when I change my browser width this button just move right box element.
[See here](http://test.gradientstudio.eu/yfs/magento/g44335-adi-sun-m.html)

I need some idea to make it look better (scaling image down,or just croping or hide it on overflow) because its very ugly how it is now.
 Thank you, hope I explain my problem easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

make the middle element (or whichever needs to be) have min-width: ###px in the css

Answer (score 0):

First i would set all `img` to `max-width: 100%;` and then fo fix the problem you are having with the add-to-cart button you should add it's class to the responsive.css stylesheet or how you call it, and play with it's positioning in the various media-queries that you have.